# regex: how to catch a number with commas separating the thousands?

Tags: python, regex

I'm writting a program in python to try to catch numbers in the format `999,999,999` I don't care about the decimal points right now. So my regex should catch the following: `123,456,789`; `42`; `3,999` but ignore `42,28,11`; `2,34`; `1234`.

I tried the following regex and it mostly works:

```
\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*
```

Problem here is, it will give the following results:

```
42,28,11 - will catch the 42, 28 AND 11
1234     - will catch the 123 AND the 4
```

If I add the caret and dollar `^\d{1,3}(,\d{3})$` will do what I want but only if the number is exactly at the beginning of the line, and the line only consist of the number. So, how can I match a formatted number with commas anywhere in the text? I'd use this to "highlight" numbers in a text.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this pattern

```
(?<!,)\b(\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*)\b(?!,)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/322)

Comment: I will change `(?!,)` to `(?!,\S)` to handle sentences like this one: `"Once uppon a time, the number was 123,456, but the sky was blue."`